# Packaging fonts for Jasper with a grails application?

Tags: grails, groovy, fonts, jasper-reports

Is there any way to include fonts within a WAR distribution such that the JVM can access them? Specifically, I need Arial, and right now, I need to run the following on ALL my servers. This can't be right.

```
For Ubuntu:
1.)  sudo aptitude install msttcorefonts

For CentOS:
1.)  As root 'yum install rpm-build cabextract'
2.)  wget http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/msttcorefonts-2.0-1.spec
3.)  As root 'rpmbuild -ba msttcorefonts-2.0-1.spec'
4.)  As root 'rpm -ivh /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/noarch/msttcorefonts-2.0-1.noarch.rpm'
```

Comment: is it allowed by msttcorefonts license?

Comment: Crap. It looks like you can't bundle the fonts for commercial use, but you can install them. Perhaps I need to modify my question to ask for an arial replacement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaging is against the licensing for this product. Find another font, or deal with environment installation.